# Resolving Time Capsule Problem Broke IPv6 Tunnel

Tags: network, time-capsule, ipv6

Some time ago my Time Capsule's light was blinking amber. When I opened the Airport Utility, it indicated that my IPv6 tunnel was down, I assume due to the remote IPv4 host being down. I was given the option to Skip or Ignore the problem. I believe when I skipped the problem, the light remained blinking amber, it wasn't until I chose the 'ignore' option that the light returned to solid green.

Since that day, I've been completely unable to use my IPv6 tunnel.

Considering that [World IPv6 Day](http://www.worldipv6day.org/) is underway, I would love for my tunnel to work again... How do I undo the damage I've previously done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that my Client IPv4 (as configured on the TunnelBroker website) had gone out of date. I was unaware my IP address had changed since after changing ISPs some time ago.

But I figured it out. Bring on the v6!